# Flask: How to Automatically Render Template When Receiving POST Request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have scripts one for a flask app and another for a barcode scanner script that sends post requests.

The flask app receieves it and decodes the JSON to the data I want to display on my html.

But how do I load these into the html? Here are the logs when the flask app receives the request:

```
Fissan Foot Powder
80.5
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2019 14:09:10] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2019 14:09:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2019 14:09:21] "GET /static/assets/img/favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and here's my code:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            r = request.data

            data = r.decode('utf-8')
            data = json.loads(data)

            item = data['item']
            price = data['price']
            print(item)
            print(price)

            return render_template('dashboard.html', item=str(item), value=str(price))
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    item = 'Test'
    price = 'Test'
    return render_template('dashboard.html', item=str(item), value=str(price))
```

What should be done in order for item and price to **display** whenever a POST request is sent to the flask app? As of now nothing is displayed on the html.

What I tried next after a suggestion:

```
# Index route
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            r = request.data

            data = r.decode('utf-8')



            return redirect(url_for('item', data=data))

        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
    item = 'Test'
    price = 'Test'
    return render_template('dashboard.html', item=str(item), value=str(price)) 




# Item route
@app.route("/item/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def item():
    data = request.args['data']
    print(str(data))
    data = json.loads(data)

    item = data['item']
    price = data['price']
    print(item)
    print(price)

    return render_template('dashboard.html', item=item, value=price)
```

In the log it says that the request is succesful with:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2019 16:35:08] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
{"item": "Fissan Foot Powder", "price": "80.5"}
Fissan Foot Powder
80.5
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Apr/2019 16:35:08] "GET /item/?data=%7B%22item%22%3A+%22Fissan+Foot+Powder%22%2C+%22price%22%3A+%2280.5%22%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

However when I look at the interface it remains the same. It didnt redirect to the url where it should go to.

also about the html I already put `{{ item }}` and `{{ value }}` in the places I want the scanned item to show to.

What I wanted to achieve is that when the request is triggered, this passes to the `/item/` route where it recieves the payload and by the GET request it should have rendered the template together with the payloads `item` and `price` as jinja on the html. And should have shown there. What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to return a redirect from a post, and to use the response from the get to display results to the user - see [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Hi Sir, I tried and succesfully passed args to a redirect, I have edited in the question what I edited. But the web isn't reloading even if the logs sats that the GET request after the POST was succesful

Comment: I have implemented it sir, but it doesn't realod to the page where I want to check out the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your dashboard.html file:

```
<p>item: {{item}} price: {{value}}</p>
```